# How do I crop an image without cutting off parts?

Tags: 8, media

I'm using Image Crop Widget (8.x-2.2) and Crop API (8.x-1.5). I'm trying to add "padding" to the cropping area so that I wouldn't have to cut my images at awkward places.

[image: Image describing issue]

In the above picture, I have a blue rectangle that must be cropped into a square. However, in #1, it cuts off a bunch. I'm looking for a solution in order to accomplish #2, to include "extra space" beyond the picture so that I don't have to cut off anything.

<sup>Hopefully, the colour of this added space, or padding, would be white, (or customizable).</sup>

Comment: You probably need another module for that kind of stuff: https://www.drupal.org/project/imagick or similar. Although it's still unclear to me what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @leymannx Thanks, I'm willing to use a module, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem. I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: For that you don't need any cropping. Just an image style and some CSS in the frontend. That's all. Cropping really is misleading here.

Comment: @leymannx Sorry for the confusion. I have a lot of different images of all sorts of sizes. I guess if you just don't do a crop that might work... Hmm...